# How can I use BeanFactory.getBean() in a test class field?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm writing test cases in which I would like to use the same BeanFactory.getBean() instance with only small changes - so I don't want to write e.g.: `Class class = factory.getBean("someName", Class.class);` every single time, but I'd rather just put it in a private field and use the `class` variable in the various test cases.

The test class looks like this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@Import(TestConfiguration.class)
public class FeedbackServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private BeanFactory beanFactory;

  //I'd like to use this in the various methods:
  private AppUser testSender = beanFactory.getBean("sender", AppUser.class);
  
  //other fields to be cleared up with BeanFactory:
  private final FeedbackRepository feedbackRepository = Mockito.mock(FeedbackRepository.class);
  private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository = Mockito.mock(AppUserRepository.class);
  private final ValueRepository valueRepository = Mockito.mock(ValueRepository.class);
  private final FeedbackService feedbackService = new FeedbackServiceImpl(feedbackRepository, appUserRepository,
      valueRepository);
  private final AppUser testTarget = new AppUser("someUserDatas"));
  private final Value testValue = new Value("someValueDatas");
  private final Feedback testFeedback = new Feedback(testSender, testValue, testTarget, "otherDatas");

  @Test
  public void saveNewFeedback_WithValidParams_ShouldSaveFeedback() {

    Mockito.when(appUserRepository.findById(testSender.getId()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(testSender));
    Mockito.when(appUserRepository.findById(testTarget.getId()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(testTarget));
    Mockito.when(valueRepository.findById(testValue.getId()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(testValue));
    feedbackService.saveNewFeedback(testFeedback);
    Mockito.verify(feedbackRepository, times(1)).save(Mockito.any(Feedback.class));
  }
```

And the TestConfiguration class is this:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "sender")
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public AppUser getAppUser() {
    return new AppUser("Pista", "pista@pista.com", Gender.MALE, "p123_ABC", "USER",
        LocalDate.parse("1967-10-12"));
  }
}
```

If I put the `private AppUser testSender = beanFactory.getBean("sender", AppUser.class);` line in the method scope, it runs fine, otherwise it throws the glorious `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then your requirement is to use reference of `testSender`  in each of method. For this I can suggest you to use @BeforeEach in `FeedbackServiceTest` 
:

```
public class FeedbackServiceTest {
    @Autowired
      private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    
      //I'd like to use this in the various methods:
      private AppUser testSender;
    
      
      @BeforeEach
      public void setBean(){
       testSender= beanFactory.getBean("sender", AppUser.class);
      }
...//rest other class
```

& then use `testSender` in each of your test method.

Edit:
Alternatively, you can use Qualifier bean if your TestConfiguration is correctly creating bean (Here no need to use @BeforeEach in this case):

```
public class FeedbackServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="sender")
    private AppUser testSender;
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is my goal, and I've tried your solution - the 'testSender' is still null when it reaches the method, but at least it doesn't throw NullPointer. Maybe I have some issues with the TestConfiguration class?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Moreover, you can try my other suggestion if your bean is still coming `null`. Also if even after trying both , its still `null` then it means your `TestConfiguration` is not creating bean properly.

Comment: Thank you! Now the test runs properly without `NullPointerException`, but the testSender is still `null`. So I thought I will just paste `testSender= beanFactory.getBean("sender", AppUser.class);` in every case I need it in. This way it works and tests pass.